# How to remove a class from a page inside onclick html attribute?

Tags: javascript

So how can I remove a class from all HTML elements on the page?

I need to to it inside the onclick html element. So:

```
<div onclick="remove class 'someClass' from all elements on the page"></div>
```

Comment: any client javascript library? Add it to your tags.

Comment: No. Just javascript wihtou any library.

Comment: Ok, I can use jquery but it must be inline javascript (inside html onclick attribute). There are reasons for that. Is that possible with jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a raw JavaScript solution (removes `some_class` class from all elements in document):

```
onclick="
for (var i = 0, elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*'); i < elements.length; i++) {
  var attr = elements[i].getAttribute('class'),
      newAttr = attr.replace(/\bsome_class\b/i, '');
  if(newAttr != attr) elements[i].setAttribute('class', attr);
}
"
```

Comment: There's no catch. The problem you've described can easily be avoided using a regular expression in the `replace()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming jQuery...

HTML:

```
<div id="my_button">Click me</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#my_button').click(function() {
  $('.some_class').removeClass('some_class');
});
```

Comment: :( But look how easy that is!

Comment: Ok. Even if I use jquery, it must be inline javascript (inside html onclick attribute). There are reasons for that. Is that possible with jquery?

Comment: It is. `onclick="$('.some_class').removeClass('some_class')"`

Comment: @Richard Knop: **Any amount of javascript code can be written inline!** Even complex multi-line scripts can be. The whole minified jQuery library is written in a single line for what it's worth. The only thing you have to be careful about are strings to not mix them with outside ones.

Answer (score 1):

to remove a class from an element

```
 element.className = element.className.replace(/className/g,'');
```

you will have to write a recursive function to go over all the element in a page using the childNodes property

```
 ReomoveClass(element, ClassName)
 {
        element.className = element.className.replace(new RegExp(ClassName,'g'),'');
        for(var i=0; i<element.childNodes;i++)
        {
             ReomoveClass(element.childNodes[i], ClassName)
        }
 }
```